# Dependency Loading & File System Mocking

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, module, mocking

So I have a dependency:

```
dep = require('dep')
```

If I mock out the file system prior to calling a function of dep, the file the dep is exported from is not found.

```
mockFs({})
dep.bar() #file where dep exported from not found
```

If I call a function prior to mocking out the file the dep is exported from is found.

```
dep.foo()
mockFs({})
dep.bar() #works
```

Any thoughts as to what would account for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your `require()` call is cached, so `dep` is using the real file system because it likely called `require('fs')`, which is not mocked yet.

Mocking `fs` later means that any **new** calls to `require('fs')` will use the mock, but anything that is loaded already is not affected.

Comment: thank you! any thoughts on getting it to go ahead and load? seems like the other functions also get loaded if calling dep.foo() beforehand

Comment: That's a tricky part regarding unit tests and mocking - the load order of the files! Typically all the `require()`s are at the top of every file, so all those dependencies are loaded because all the files are loaded first, before your first test file (and first mock) is even run! Some mocking libraries have "spies" that can take over existing functions, or even the require cache. And sometimes you can change where those `require()` calls are called, in order to effectively mock them.

Comment: any thoughts as to what I had not accounted for in terms of the file associated with the dependency not being found when calling the second function in scenario 2 above? with dependency being required before all code. and thank you!

Comment: I can't tell from what's there, sorry. One way to go about something like this is to store the object that needs to be mocked as a variable in something you have access to. Like, if a lot of logic had access to a `server` object, they could make calls to the file system from `server.fs`, and before your test runs, you mock `server.fs` (setting it back afterwards).